# Вертикальная полоса в phpStorm

Tags: ide, phpstorm

Недавно откуда-то нарисовалась вертикальная белая полоса в phpStorm от jetBrains.
Нарисовалась хрен сотрешь - на скриншоте выделена красным
http://savepic.net/5863989.htm
Эта полоса меня очень раздражает, распространяется на весь код и оказывается сверху любого текста.
Кто знает как ее отключить?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Это не ужасная, а очень полезная полоса. Пока она есть на экране, за нее не хочется залезать, и в результате не получается выходящих за пределы экрана портянок, как на картине. Отдельно напомню, что PEP8 и PSR2 требуют/рекомендуют не выходить за пределы 80 символов. Если придется когда-нибудь редактировать конфиг по ssh - поймете, почему так важно, чтобы весь код умещался на одном экране.

В опциях ее можно найти по ключевому слову margin (ide settings - editor - appearance - show right margin). Поправить ее значение можно в project settings - code style - general, но всеми рекомендуемое значение - 80 символов.

Comment: Огромное спасибо за развернутый ответ!

Comment: о спасибо за ответ, а наоборот искал этот параметр чтобы раздвинуть эту полосу по ближе в коду для  PEP8 и PSR2 ;), а то она стояла на 120 и не зная иногда писал код больше 80 строк, теперь этим параметром такое не будет)

Comment: А можно глупый вопрос: если выходить за пределы линии то это влияет на скорость выполнения кода?

Comment: @bemulima конечно нет